# Save a Mesh file under VTK

Tags: c++, vtk, marching-cubes

I'm trying to generate a mesh from a 3d volume.
I processed on VTK, using Marching Cube (vtkMarchingCubes.h); but I still can't found how to save the result view, as vtk file!

any idea

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [vtkPolyDataWriter](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataWriter.html) or [vtkXMLPolyDataWriter](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkXMLPolyDataWriter.html) to write the mesh data to files.
- If you want the write the rendered output in a window you can use [vtkWindowToImageFilter](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/Screenshot) as a starting point
- You can find some examples [here](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/#working-with-meshes)
- [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/) is a very nice tool to visualize the files.

Comment: Hi @Shreyas,

In fact, before posting my question, I tried with vtkPolyDataWriter but it doesn't work!

I checked again, and now it's working.

 
Thank you.